# Finding a function's address in memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, memory

For fun I wanted to disassemble my c++ code and I learned how a program call a function, I learned that the byte 0xE8 represent the call instruction followed by 4 bytes which lead to the wanted function first instruction. By using the visual studio Memory viewer the 4 bytes that come after the 0xE8 instruction byte doesn't lead to the function's first instruction aka the function address.

For an example

The printf address is 046FC90h -> What does the "h" mean?

The 4 bytes that I was able to extract are 53 d1 06 00

[image]

Comment: _"What does the "h" mean?"_ That thhe value is shown in hexadecimal repesentation.

Comment: E8 is a call with relative offset, not with an absolute address.

Comment: @George It's a postfix denoting that the value is in hex representation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah right thankyou, didn't know that either.

Comment: Thanks all for reaching out @πάνταῥεῖ made it clear. So if you want to call a function by its address just subtract the current address from the absolute address.

Answer (score 1):

Hello as your C code is set out like this

```cpp
void Func() {
    printf("Just a Func");
}
```

We have a function that we call and it prints `Just a Func`, To get this functions address we can prefix it with `&`, Such as `&Func`

The h you see represents hexadecimal (Base 16) and the number you see can be represented in 3 ways but not all are supported by every compiler, `046FC90h` and `0x046FC90` which in decimal means `4652176`

But the original question asked was how do we get the function address and that is the `&` operator.

```cpp
void Func() {
    printf("Just a Func");
}

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    printf("addr = %i", &Func); // print address to terminal
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is unrelated but thanks for contributing.

Comment: You have asked how to obtain the function address and i provided.

Comment: Although your answer was helpful :) but I was looking to obtain the function address from the memory after the call instruction not by using the typical way.

Comment: In this case you are looking at how instructions are encoded